# Using std::get and std::tie on boost tuples, zip_iterator, etc

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl, tuples

What are my options for using `std::get<>()` and `std::tie<>()` together with boost constructs?

Example:
I want to use range-based for-loop for iteration over several containers. I can implement `zip` function, which uses `boost::zip_iterator`.

```
 #include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>
 #include <boost/range.hpp>

 template <typename... TContainer>
 auto zip(TContainer&... containers) -> boost::iterator_range<boost::zip_iterator<decltype(boost::make_tuple(std::begin(containers)...))>> {
    auto zip_begin = boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(std::begin(containers)...));
    auto zip_end = boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(std::end(containers)...));
    return boost::make_iterator_range(zip_begin, zip_end);
 }
```

Now I can use it like this:

```
std:list<int> a;
std::vector<double> b;
...
for (auto t : zip(a, b)) {
   // access elements by boost::get<0>(t), boost::get<1>(t)
   // or use boost::tie(a_element, b_element)
}
```

Problems occur when I call some other method, which expects `std::tuple` or `std::pair` - I have to convert), since rest of the code uses `std::tuples`, or when templated code uses `std::get<>()` and/or `std::tie()`.

I found some patches which add `std::tuple` support for `zip_iterator`, but these are not applied in my version (I use Boost 1.54).

Am I missing something? What are my options to either force `zip_iterator` to return `std::tuple` or make `std::get`, `std::tie`, etc. available for boost types?

Comment: Unfortunately, these patches still have not been applied, even in version 1.55. Here's a link to the ticket: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7526. It seems like there hasn't been any activity, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @void-pointer A fix with boost::fusion has been committed and merged in March 2017: https://github.com/boostorg/iterator/pull/2 and is available in Boost 1.64.0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <tuple>

template <typename... TContainer> auto zip(TContainer&... containers) ->
boost::iterator_range<boost::zip_iterator<decltype(std::make_tuple(std::begin(containers)...))>> {
                                                   ^^^
    auto zip_begin = boost::make_zip_iterator(std::make_tuple(std::begin(containers)...));
                                              ^^^
    auto zip_end = boost::make_zip_iterator(std::make_tuple(std::end(containers)...));
                                            ^^^
    return boost::make_iterator_range(zip_begin, zip_end);
 }
```

Comment: Yes I have. But it seems that Boost is missing some type traits for std::tuple. These are added by those patches I mentioned, but I don't see them in my version of Boost. Maybe I need to include some other header (like for std::tuple adapter in Boost.Fusion).

Answer (score 0):

use `boost::combine` in boost >= 1.55.

`for (auto a_tuple: boost::combine(va, vb))
{...}`

or

`BOOST_FOREACH(boost::tie(elem_a, elem_b), boost::combine(va, vb))
{...}`

Comment: This replaces my implementation of `zip` function - good to know. But it has exactly the same problem with `std::tie` and `std::tuple` as I mentioned. It returns range of zip iterators which cannot be dereferenced to `std::tuple`. Maybe I am missing something ...

Comment: Yes, but that was not my question - I asked about usage of STL tools, since the rest of the code uses `stl:tuple`, `std:tie`, etc.

Comment: Yes, I had the same question, but I think the boost_foreach with boost::tie is clean enough. Instead of  `std::tuple`->`std::tie`, you could just `std::make_tuple` again with the `elem_a, elem_b` if a `std::tuple` is unavoidable. So I think it does not make sense to stick to `std::tie` a `boost::tuple`.