# Conversion of data type using auto in C++

Tags: c++11

I have 2 vector container which contains 2 different kind of value with data type **uint32_t**. I want to print both of them together.
Like this is what I have

```
vector<uint32_t> data1;
vector<uint32_t> data2;
```

Now I know a method for single data like below

```
for(auto const& d1: data1)
   cout<< d1 << endl;
```

But I want to print both data together like this,

```
   cout<< d1 << "\t" << d2 << endl;
```

How can I do this using auto? (where d2 is auto converted value from data2)

Comment: What's the type of `data1`?

Comment: `vector<uint32_t> data1`

Comment: Oh, so you've got `vector<uint32_t> data1` and `vector<uint32_t> data2`, and you want to display each value from `data1` alongside the corresponding value (same index) from `data2`?

Comment: I am sorry for less information. Please see the edited question and give some suggestion.

Comment: What are you expecting your `uint32_t` to be converted into?

Comment: normal integer like `int`

Comment: @HarshPatel `auto` will not convert the type. And there is no reason to convert anyway. `std::cout` can output a `unint32_t` fine.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Thank you very much for your answer. I know if I want to only print, it can be done without conversion (just using iteration or just like you mentioned below as answer). I was concerning about conversion because I want to use those values for comparison (want to save all the value in a different container which are above threshold). Sorry I didn't write my question in detail, but I thought it'd be more complicated.

Comment: @HarshPatel I've edited my answer with some info about converting the `unint32_t` to an `int`.

Comment: @ChrisDrew thanks for the suggestion. I wanted to convert because I need that data for clustering. And I think I can create better cluster if I can convert them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a normal for loop over the index:

```
for (auto i = 0u; i != n; ++i)
    std::cout << data1[i] << "\t" << data2[i] << "\n";
```

**Edit**: if you want to convert the `uint32_t` to an `int`, for example, you could do:

```
auto d1 = static_cast<int>(data1[i]);
```

but it is up to you to ensure the conversion is safe. i.e the value fits in the target type.

Comment: I had kind of assumed OP wanted something fancier, but, well, yeah. +1.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm still not sure want OP wants.

Comment: @einpoklum I am sorry I am quite new to stackoverflow (and also programming). So could you tell me what does OP means?

Comment: Is it like "Original Publisher"?

Comment: @HarshPatel "Orignal Poster", i.e you

Answer (score 2):

Use the Boost [Zip Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html), which will let you have a range of pairs rather than two ranges of the vectors' data types. Something along the lines of:

```
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename... TContainer>
auto zip(TContainer&... containers) -> boost::iterator_range<boost::zip_iterator<decltype(boost::make_tuple(std::begin(containers)...))>> {
    auto zip_begin = boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(std::begin(containers)...));
    auto zip_end = boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(std::end(containers)...));
    return boost::make_iterator_range(zip_begin, zip_end);
}

int main()
{
        std::vector<uint32_t> data1( { 11, 22, 33 } );
        std::vector<uint32_t> data2( { 44, 55, 66 } );
        for (auto t : zip(data1, data2)) {
                std::cout << boost::get<0>(t) << "\t" << boost::get<1>(t) << "\n";
        }
}
```

The `zip()` function is due to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22659287/1593077) and you can put it in a separate header file since it's not specific to your case.

Answer (score 1):

#### If possible (and plausible for your use case): work with a container of pairs

If your application is not in a bind w.r.t. computer resources, and you know that you will be working with the values of your two containers as pairs (assuming same-length containers, as in your example), it might be useful to actually work with a container of pairs, which also ease the use of the neat range-based `for` loops ( >= C++11).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::vector<uint32_t> data1 = {1, 2, 3};
  std::vector<uint32_t> data2 = {4, 5, 6};

  // construct container of (int, int) pairs
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> data;
  data.reserve(data1.size());
  std::transform(data1.begin(), data1.end(), data2.begin(), std::back_inserter(data),
                 [](uint32_t first, uint32_t second) {
                   return std::make_pair(static_cast<int>(first), static_cast<int>(second));
                 });   /* as noted in accepted answer: you're responsible for
                          ensuring that the conversion here is safe */

  // easily use range-based for loops to traverse of the
  // pairs of your container
  for(const auto& pair: data) {
    std::cout << pair.first << " " << pair.second << "\n";
  } /* 1 4
       2 5
       3 6 */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @HarshPatel happy to help.